# how to create database in visual studio 2010 when sql server installed?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I want to create a database(.mdf) within my website. When i try to add sql server database by:

right clicking the project->add new item->Sql Server Database. I get the following error:[image]

I have sql server 2008 installed on my machine and i have been using it to connect to different databases of sql server by going in the "Server Explorer" section of Visual Studio, as shown below:
[image]

But when i try to create a database with my website, i am having problems. I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Please help?

Comment: Why don't you just create a database in SQL Server and then point your web site at it?

Comment: If I understand, you want to manage your database inside visual studio, so, try adding a database project.

Comment: I want to create a database within my website as the server where i will host it, there will be no sql server installed. so i cant just point it to a dataase, i have to use one created within my asp.net website.